Images no longer upload to storage after update from 8.0 to 10.0
Any reason why images are not uploading to this storage? Weird thing is I'm not seeing any errors being thrown.
public function saveImage($image, ?string $path): string
{
    $save_path = $path ?? 'temp/image';

    try {
        if (!file_exists(public_path($path))) {
            mkdir(public_path($path), 0777, true);
        }
        $result = Storage::disk('public')->put($save_path, $image);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception('No save image! ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(), 500);
    }

    return $this->returnBasePath($result);
}


In Laravel 10, you can simply use the below. If the folder does not exist, it will be created. Also, make sure to run php artisan storage:link. If you get an error, delete public/storage, and run it again to create the symlink
public function update(Request $request): string
    {
        $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
 
        return $path;
    }

